# Django internationalization performance issues (3-4s vs 300ms with USE_I18N=False)

Tags: django, performance, internationalization

So, we have a page with quite a lot of information on in, and we use {% trans %} a lot, but when we actually use them (USE_I18N=True) the site grinds to a halt, ~3.5 seconds with i18n vs 300ms with it off.

We did some profiling and it seems the translation initialization takes forever.

```
20.2%   0.503 /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/translation/__init__.py
15.3%   0.383 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py
11.4%   0.285 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/gettext.py
 8.6%   0.215 /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/formats.py
 8.5%   0.212 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py
 8.3%   0.206 /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py
 7.6%   0.189 /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py
```

We tried wrapping the {% trans %} blocks into another templatetag which caches the translations, but that only gained a couple of ms, and the pages are not really that cacheable (except for the translations of course).

Anyone have any experience with this, and/or some pointers on how to make this go faster? Or any pitsfalls we might have gotten ourselfs into?

Answer (score 3):

Seems L10N (new in django 1.2) was the sinner. We solved it by not enabling it (as we use ISO formats everywhere anyways).

Probably should report this to django.. :-)

Comment: +1: nice, i'll be using this soon, good to know! and definitely report it!

Answer (score 1):

Bin your custom caches and try some [template fragment cacheing](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) - the docs linked show how you can use it with i18n